# Modify Self, Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
module Pigged
  String.class_eval do
    def pig
      newstring = self + self[0]; newstring[0] = ""; newstring += "ay"
      return newstring
    end
  end
end
```

is the relevant code. What I want to do is make a method, `pig!`, that modifies the original string. How do I do that, without modifying self, because that is not allowed...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't modify self.

Use `replace` or a custom method.

Read '[Writing method "change!" for String](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/110734)' for more information.

Comment: Not really. There are *tons* of things in the library that do. Take `String#<<`, for example. That modifies the existing string and is one of the most used methods in all of Ruby programming (behind things like `puts` and `+`).

Answer (score 15):

I've condensed your code a little and added the `pig!` method :

```
module Pigged
  String.class_eval do
    def pig
      self[1..-1] + self[0] + 'ay'
    end
    def pig!
      self.replace(pig) #self.replace(self[1..-1] + self[0] + 'ay')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `pig!` should just be `self.replace pig` to avoid repeating the common calculation.

Comment: I liked this answer better than the excepted answer because you supplied a solution. Guess I'm lazy - but why make us click another link?

Answer (score 4):

For String, you can use self.replace to change the content.

For other classes, I do not think it can modify itself unless creating a new object.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong about modifying `self`, you can't assign to it, but you can use accessor methods to modify it or modify instance variables if you have direct access to them. `String#replace` is an accessor in this particular case.

Another example:

```
class Array
  def delete_first_element!
    self[0..0] = []
  end
end

a = [1,2,3]
b = a

a.delete_first_element!

puts a.inspect # [2,3]
puts b.inspect # [2,3]!
```

One thing to remember -- you change all references of the same object (`b` in my example)!